# Assign Values to Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function

There are two 'select' field inside the [Form](http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register). One for Country and the other for State. I want to assign a value to a field of Country and State using Java Script. If you select a Country by hand! the values for State are changed using Java Script. But if you assign a value using Java Script (or JQuery), as follows, the values for State won't change!

> element.value = "Canada"
>
> $(element).val("Canada")

is there any way for assigning value to the field of Country and trigger the function which will change the values for State?

Comment: Yes, you have to `trigger` the event you want to run. Post your current country `change` script. The answer is probably `.val(val).change()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger a change by element.value = "Canada", but you can do it with jQuery's equivalent $(element).val("Canada"). To do that, have a look at $.valHooks. I have used it a while ago and it works just like I wanted it to, however, the valHooks are not very well documented. I have found this example http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/11-jQuery-Hooks.html (which I think I have used back then) so have a look at it, it might be helpful.